# Glossaries: glsreset conflicts with indexonlyfirst

Tags: glossaries

To my surprise, the acronym TEST is listed twice in the glossary.
It appears that this is the case due to the glsreset.
How can I still only display the first use in the document?

The [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) on page 94 states in the red box that this is a known behavior. But I do not understand if it can be changed.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indexonlyfirst=true]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym
    {TEST}{Short Test}{Long Test}
\newacronym
    {FOO}{Short Foo}{Long Foo}

\begin{document}

\gls{TEST}
\gls{FOO}
\glsreset{FOO}
\gls{FOO}
\newpage
a
\glsreset{TEST}
\gls{TEST}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after the red box the manual describe the command `\glswriteentry` which is responsible for the information written to the external file. You can redefine it locally to do nothing

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indexonlyfirst=true]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym
    {TEST}{Short Test}{Long Test}
\newacronym
    {FOO}{Short Foo}{Long Foo}

\begin{document}

\gls{TEST}
\gls{FOO}
\glsreset{FOO}
\gls{FOO}
\newpage
a
\glsreset{TEST}
{\renewcommand*{\glswriteentry}[2]{}\gls{TEST}}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

If you will use this a more than a few times, you should probably create a macro for that, say `\newcommand\mygls[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand*{\glswriteentry}[2]{}\glslocalreset{#1}\gls{#1}\endgroup}`

Then use as the following

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indexonlyfirst=true]{glossaries}
\newcommand\mygls[1]{\begingroup
        \renewcommand*{\glswriteentry}[2]{}%
        \glslocalreset{#1}%
        \gls{#1}\endgroup}
\makenoidxglossaries
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym
    {TEST}{Short Test}{Long Test}
\newacronym
    {FOO}{Short Foo}{Long Foo}

\begin{document}

\gls{TEST}
\gls{FOO}
\glsreset{FOO}
\gls{FOO}
\newpage
a
\mygls{TEST}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

### Edit

You can add a conditional for each acronym that will be set to true after the first use of the acronym, then redefine `\glswriteentry` to print the page number only if the conditional is false. The following code will do it, but only for acronyms, not a general glossary entry

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[indexonlyfirst=true]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\def\@gls@#1#2[#3]{%
    \glsdoifexists{#2}%
    {%
        \let\do@gls@link@checkfirsthyper\@gls@link@checkfirsthyper
        \let\glsifplural\@secondoftwo
        \let\glscapscase\@firstofthree
        \let\glscustomtext\@empty
        \def\glsinsert{#3}%
        \def\@glo@text{\csname gls@\glstype @entryfmt\endcsname}%
        \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
        \@gls@do@glsunset{#2}%
    }%
    \glspostlinkhook
    \csname #2@used@beforetrue\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\glswriteentry}[2]{%
    \csname if#1@used@before\endcsname
    \else
    #2%
    \fi
}

\makenoidxglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\NewCommandCopy\oldnewacronym\newacronym % must be after \setacronymstyle
\renewcommand*\newacronym[4][]{\expandafter\newif\csname if#2@used@before\endcsname\oldnewacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}} % must be after \setacronymstyle

\newacronym
{TEST}{Short Test}{Long Test}
\newacronym
{FOO}{Short Foo}{Long Foo}

\begin{document}
    
    \gls{TEST}
    \gls{FOO}
    \glsreset{FOO}
    \gls{FOO}
    \newpage
    a
    \glsreset{TEST}
    \gls{TEST}
    
    \printnoidxglossaries
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just did not really understand what `glswriteentry` is doing. However, your solution does not really work well for me because I am using `glsresetall` and `glsreset` multiple times in my document and with your solution I would need to check basically all entries manually whether they have been used and reset before. I suppose I would rather write a script to filter the aux file instead. Sadly the journal I am submitting to will certainly not do that. So for now, I am omitting the numbers.

Comment: @RonnieMarksch, Your problem refers only to acronyms?

Comment: Yes, only acronyms. I believe that the only thing missing is a kind of set `S` that is initially empty and `glswriteentry` checking for a given acronym whether it is in `S` adding the acronym to `S` when it is not already contained also adding in that case the page to the list. It is just surprising to me that this is not part of the package since my use case seems not very extraordinary; I just have some acronyms that appear on average on 50% of the pages making it useless to list all these pages.

Comment: @RonnieMarksch If you use just a small amount of acronyms types maybe it would be more efficient to add a conditional for each one, and make the conditional true only if the acronym has been used before.

Comment: @RonnieMarksch see my edit